# HuggingFace for Japanese tokenizer

Tags: python, cjk, bert-language-model

I recently tested on the below code based on the source:
https://github.com/cl-tohoku/bert-japanese/blob/master/masked_lm_example.ipynb

```
import torch 
from transformers.tokenization_bert_japanese import BertJapaneseTokenizer
from transformers.modeling_bert import BertForMaskedLM

tokenizer = BertJapaneseTokenizer.from_pretrained('cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-whole-word-masking')
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-whole-word-masking')

input_ids = tokenizer.encode(f'''
    青葉山で{tokenizer.mask_token}の研究をしています。
''', return_tensors='pt')
```

when i try to encode it, I received error such as:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-f8582275f4db> in <module>
      1 input_ids = tokenizer.encode(f'''
      2     青葉山で{tokenizer.mask_token}の研究をしています。
----> 3 ''', return_tensors='pt')

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/envs/personal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in encode(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, return_tensors, **kwargs)
   1428             stride=stride,
   1429             return_tensors=return_tensors,
-> 1430             **kwargs,
   1431         )
   1432 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/envs/personal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in encode_plus(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, is_pretokenized, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
   1740             return_length=return_length,
   1741             verbose=verbose,
-> 1742             **kwargs,
   1743         )
   1744 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/envs/personal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py in _encode_plus(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding_strategy, truncation_strategy, max_length, stride, is_pretokenized, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
    452             )
    453 
--> 454         first_ids = get_input_ids(text)
    455         second_ids = get_input_ids(text_pair) if text_pair is not None else None
    456 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/envs/personal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py in get_input_ids(text)
    423         def get_input_ids(text):
    424             if isinstance(text, str):
--> 425                 tokens = self.tokenize(text, **kwargs)
    426                 return self.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)
    427             elif isinstance(text, (list, tuple)) and len(text) > 0 and isinstance(text[0], str):

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/envs/personal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py in tokenize(self, text, **kwargs)
    362 
    363         no_split_token = self.unique_no_split_tokens
--> 364         tokenized_text = split_on_tokens(no_split_token, text)
    365         return tokenized_text
    366 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/envs/personal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py in split_on_tokens(tok_list, text)
    356                     (
    357                         self._tokenize(token) if token not in self.unique_no_split_tokens else [token]
--> 358                         for token in tokenized_text
    359                     )
    360                 )

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/envs/personal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    356                     (
    357                         self._tokenize(token) if token not in self.unique_no_split_tokens else [token]
--> 358                         for token in tokenized_text
    359                     )
    360                 )

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/envs/personal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_bert_japanese.py in _tokenize(self, text)
    153     def _tokenize(self, text):
    154         if self.do_word_tokenize:
--> 155             tokens = self.word_tokenizer.tokenize(text, never_split=self.all_special_tokens)
    156         else:
    157             tokens = [text]

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/envs/personal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_bert_japanese.py in tokenize(self, text, never_split, **kwargs)
    205                 break
    206 
--> 207             token, _ = line.split("\t")
    208             token_start = text.index(token, cursor)
    209             token_end = token_start + len(token)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Does anyone experienced this before? I tried a lot of different ways and refer to many posts but all using the same methods and no explanations, I just wanted to test multiple languages, other languages seem to work fine but not with japanese and I dont know why.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: The code supposed to encode the sentence. Its a tokenizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: Shortly after this question I released a version of IPADic that works with the latest versions of mecab-python3. You should be able to fix things by installing `transformers[ja]`, which will install the main dictionaries used with HuggingFace models.

---

I'm the mecab-python3 maintainer. Transformers relies on the bundled dictionary in versions prior to 1.0, which has been removed because it's old. I will be adding it as an option in a release soon, but in the meantime you can install an old version.

The command posted by vivasra doesn't work because it specifies a version of a different package (notice there's no "3" in the package name) that doesn't exist. You can use this:

```
pip install mecab-python3=0.996.5
```

If you still have trouble please open an issue [on Github](https://github.com/SamuraiT/mecab-python3/issues).

Comment: Thank you but I do not know why, I did not install the old version but somehow it work perfectly fine right now. Did you update the script? Thank you again

Comment: What happened is HuggingFace was using the package with no version specification, so when I released a new version that didn't work it broke. After noticing the issue they updated their code to specify the old version.

Comment: Thank you so much. In the future if I have more questions about mecab-python3 installer, should I keep posting on stackoverflow or should they be any specific place i should visit? Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: I only check here every so often, if you have a bug or trouble installing I'll see an issue on Github quickly.

Answer (score 0):

With a quick check, no errors for me, maybe there are some version issues in your case?

From what it looks like, the error occurs with the BertJapaneseTokenizer, so possibly the version of the tokenizer (mecab?) that you have is incompatible with your environment.

The mecab-python in my environment:

```
!pip list | grep mecab
#mecab-python3  0.996.5
```

Maybe you could create a new environment or try the below (or some other available version):

```
!pip install 'mecab-python3==0.996.5' --force-reinstall
```

Edit: fixed the environment setting (thanks, @polm23)

Comment: thank you and i received this error when i run the force reinstall "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
"

Comment: @Anony That can be caused by a totally other range of problems, probably not related to you original problem here. Just create a new clean environment and see if you can get it to work.